Roots Oxtongue tent fly pole missing
I have a Roots Outdoor Oxtongue 6 person tent (model # 076-6017-7) and somehow have lost the short fibreglass fly pole. This tent is discontinued and the customer service support doesn't carry replacement parts for this tent. I don't know the size of the pole to order one from Camp Pole Technology. Does anyone have this tent and could you tell me the length of the short fibreglass fly pole so I can order this? Thanks.

Googling "aftermarket replacement tent poles" brings up a number of possible vendors. Getting the size is mostly measuring where it goes and adding a bit for tension. Some replacement poles are adjustable length.

@JonCuster excellent advice! For the length I would thread the longer pole through and then mark where it should be ending.

Thank you for these suggestions. Much appreciated.
